# Assigning the result of 'test' to a variable

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script where I need to use the output of a file test in several places, including inside a shell function. I would like to assign the file existence to a shell variable, like this: `file_exists=[ -f $myfile ]`.

Just to make sure that I've got my bases covered, I start by touching a file, and testing its existance:

```
file='a'
touch $file
if [ -f $file ]
then
    echo "1 -- '$file' exists"
fi
```

Output:

```
1 -- 'a' exists
```

The file was created successfully -- no surprises, but at least I know that I'm not dealing with any permissions issues or anything.

Next I test to make sure that I can store a boolean expression in a variable:

```
mytest=/bin/true

if $mytest
then
    echo "2 -- \$mytest is true"
fi
```

Output:

```
2 -- $mytest is true
```

So I've got the basics covered -- conditional expressions should emit the same output as `/bin/true` or `/bin/false`... but that's not what I'm seeing:

```
mytest=[ -f $file ]
if $mytest
then
    echo "3 -- \$mytest is true [expect true]"
else
    echo "3 -- \$mytest is false [expect true]"
fi
```

This fails with the following error:

```
-f: command not found
```

I get the same error message if i use `test -f $file` rather than `[ -f $file ]`.

If I put a space in front of the `[`, the error goes away...

```
mytest= [ -f $file ]
if $mytest
then
    echo "4 -- \$mytest is true [expect true]"
else
    echo "4 -- \$mytest is false [expect true]"
fi
```

The output appears to be correct:

```
4 -- $mytest is true [expect true]
```

... but if I remove the file, I should get the opposite result:

```
rm $file
mytest= [ -f $file ]
if $mytest
then
    echo "5 -- \$mytest is true [expect false]"
else
    echo "5 -- \$mytest is false [expect false]"
fi
```

... and I don't:

```
5 -- $mytest is true [expect false]
```

To be fair, I expected the space to mess with the truth value:

```
mytest= /bin/false
if $mytest
then
    echo "6 -- \$mytest is true [expect false]"
else
    echo "6 -- \$mytest is false [expect false]"
fi
```

Outputs:

```
6 -- $mytest is true [expect false]
```

So, how do I store the output from the `test` builtin in a shell variable?

Comment: `mytest=/bin/true` this is storing the **string** `/bin/true` in the `$mytest` variable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As others have documented here, using the string "true" is a red herring; this is *not* an appropriate way to store boolean values in shell scripts, as evaluating it means dynamically invoking a command rather than simply inspecting the stored value using shell builtins hardcoded in your script.

Instead, if you really must store an exit status, do so as a numeric value:

```
[ -f "$file" ]               # run the test
result=$?                    # store the result

if (( result == 0 )); then   # 0 is success
  echo "success"
else                         # nonzero is failure
  echo "failure"
fi
```

If compatibility with `set -e` is desired, replace the first two lines of the above with:

```
result=0
[ -f "$file" ] || result=$?
```

...as putting the test on the left-hand side of `||` marks it as "checked", suppressing `errexit` behavior. (That said, see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) describing the extent to which `set -e` harms predictable, portable behavior; I strongly advise against its use).

Comment: What is the benefit of using (( x == y )) vs using [ $x -eq $y ] ?

Comment: @Silwing, the biggest advantage is that you don't need to quote it to correctly handle empty strings, insane IFS values (containing digits), strings that have spaces in them, etc. `[ "$x" -eq "$y" ]` doesn't have those problems either, but it's more of a mouthful.

Comment: @Silwing, ...beyond that, `(( ))` is a general-purpose (C-like) arithmetic context, so there's a lot of flexibility to it; you can use the ternary operator in it, for example, which outside such a context bash doesn't support at all, so one can run `if (( foo == (bar ? baz : qux) ))` to compare `foo` against either `baz` or `qux`, depending on the value of `bar`.

Comment: @Barton Chittenden, this code _can_ be made compatible with `set -e` by connecting the operation to the assignment with `||`. As such, an edit addressing compatibility should describe how to fix it, not just say it's unavailable. (The other thing is that I hesitate to do anything that could be seen as promoting the use of errexit; the feature is one big design flaw, as described in [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)).

Comment: excellent, thank you.   you wrote it in a comment but it might bear repeating: 0 is success.  so subsequent logic testing $result needs to take that into account.

Answer (score 9):

You need to quote whitespace:

```
mytest='[ -f $file ]'
if $mytest; then echo yes; fi
```

However, this is extremely brittle and potentially insecure. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for a detailed discussion and some better ways to accomplish something similar.

If you want to encapsulate a complex piece of code, a function is usually the way to go:

```
mytest () { [ -f "$file" ]; }
if mytest; then echo yes; fi
```

If you want to run the code once and store its result so you can examine it later, I would rephrase it like this:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    mytest=true
else
    mytest=false
fi
if $mytest; then echo yes; fi
```

Comment: I'm split here; BashFAQ #50 reference is always worth mentioning, but showing `mytest=[ -f $file ]` without showing a better practice right alongside is arguably encouraging the lazy to use it despite the warning.

Comment: I'd have to agree, but I really cannot guess what the OP actually wants this for.

Comment: I'm not sure that any guessing is necessary; can you think of any use case (*any* use case) where the sample represents an appropriate practice as presently given?

Comment: ...encouraging folks to *store a command name in a variable*, and execute that command (unquoted, even) to run a test? Really?

Comment: I tested this a bit and confirm that this sets **mytest** to the string: "`[ -f $file ]`".  Better to use the preferred answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24896746/108350, from tripleee.

Answer (score 3):

`mytest=/bin/true` is storing the **string** `/bin/true` in the `$mytest` variable.

`mytest=[ -f $file ]` is setting the `$mytest` variable to the value `[` for the duration of the command `-f $file ]` (which as your output indicates fails as there is no `-f` command available).

`mytest= [ -f $file ]` (like the above) sets the value of the `$mytest` variable to blank for the duration of the `[ -f $file ]` command (and returns whatever `[` returns).

`mytest= /bin/false` this is the same as the above case only the command being run is `/bin/false`.

If you want to store the return code from a command in a variable you can do

```
/bin/true
ret=$?
```

if you want to store the output from a command in a variable you can do

```
out=$(/bin/true)
```

(though with `/bin/true` that variable will be empty as it outputs no text.

For your case you want the former `$?` model.

Also, using `set -x` (and/or `set -v`) in your scripts might have helped you diagnose this.

Comment: actually, this comes to grief a bit later... when I store the value of `$?`, I can't re-test it later -- `testme=$?; if $testme; then echo "ts-da"; else echo "bzzzt"; fi` gives `-bash: 0: command not found`, because the `if` statement is trying to run its argument as a command and evaluate the success of that command.

Comment: Correct, you don't run the variable. You check its value. Is it `0` or something else. `if [ "$testme" -eq 0 ]; then`

Answer (score 3):

A old one but left this here for reference for people that might need it. Not the most beautiful solution but it works in bash:

```
mytest=$( [ -f $file ] ; echo $? )
```

More portable, using the test command, and the backticks:

```
set mytest=`test -f $file ; echo $?`
```

In a subprocess (<!> system load), the condition is evaluated, and then the result echoed to the output that is captured by the variable $mytest.

Answer (score 1):

Different version with test command.

```sh
fileExists=$(test -f /path/to/file && echo true || echo false)
if [[ ${fileExists} == "true" ]]; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

Or even more simplier version.

```sh
fileExists=$(test -f /path/to/file && echo 1)
if [[ -z ${fileExists} ]]; then
    # Your code here
fi
```

Comment: In the first example can't `if [ $fileExists ]` work?

Comment: Indeed, the braces are superfluous here; though in the general case, probably quote the variable. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)